# Batch fetching returning null in JPA(Eclipse-Link)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, eclipselink

I have a query that batch fetch query that is being executed against two tables. These are the relations between them.

```
//CATEGORY_ON_PAGE
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name="CATEGORY_ON_PAGE")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "fieldHandler"})
@EntityListeners({JPAtoEOFChangeNotifier.class, JPAObjectChangeSubscriber.class})
@Was(com.stratahealth.shared.model.CategoryOnPage.class)
public class CategoryOnFormJPAImpl implements CategoryOnForm {

@NotNull @ManyToOne(targetEntity=CategoryJPAImpl.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
@org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetch(value=org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetchType.JOIN,size=990)
private Category category;

}

//CATEGORY ENTITY
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
@EntityListeners({JPAtoEOFChangeNotifier.class, JPAObjectChangeSubscriber.class})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "fieldHandler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Was(com.stratahealth.shared.model.Category.class)
public class CategoryJPAImpl implements Category {

@OneToMany(targetEntity=CategoryOnFormJPAImpl.class, mappedBy="category")
private Set<CategoryOnForm> categoryForms;
```

The relationship is on the categorys on a form. When the BatchFetch retrieves the category for the page, a null pointer is thrown. This is the stack trace.

```
javax.el.ELException: //usr/local/jsp/loader_194859196/META-INF/resources/informationProfile.xhtml @28,59 listener="#{editInformationProfileController.init()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2486)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2163)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2111)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.common.filters.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.clickspace.csutilities.jsf.UTF8CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(UTF8CharacterEncodingFilter.java:15)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.common.filters.RequireLoginFilter.doFilter(RequireLoginFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.executeBatchQuery(OneToOneMapping.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.extractResultFromBatchQuery(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.BatchValueHolder.instantiate(BatchValueHolder.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.model.restimpl.jpa.CategoryOnFormJPAImpl._persistence_get_category(CategoryOnFormJPAImpl.java)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.model.restimpl.jpa.CategoryOnFormJPAImpl.getCategory(CategoryOnFormJPAImpl.java:60)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.common.services.impl.CategoryServiceImpl.sortedCategoriesForFormWithCareTypes(CategoryServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.common.controllers.EditInformationProfileController.getCategoriesOnFormForCareType(EditInformationProfileController.java:1421)
    at com.stratahealth.shared.common.controllers.EditInformationProfileController.init(EditInformationProfileController.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 49 more
```

Inside the ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery method, a null pointer is being thrown. This is because the "TranslationRow" is being rendered as null. But this is not consistent, I have only been able to reproduce this by luck.

The line where the NPE is:

```
Object sopObject = getTranslationRow().getSopObject();
```

When getTranslationRow() is called, a null value is return and the exception is thrown. This is the method where the NPE is happening inside the Eclipse Link library.

```
  /**
     * INTERNAL:
     * Execute the query.
     * Get the rows and build the object from the rows.
     * @exception  DatabaseException - an error has occurred on the database
     * @return java.lang.Object collection of objects resulting from execution of query.
     */
    @Override
    protected Object executeObjectLevelReadQuery() throws DatabaseException {
        Object result = null;

        if (this.containerPolicy.overridesRead()) {
            this.executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return this.containerPolicy.execute();
        }

        if (this.descriptor.isDescriptorForInterface()) {
            Object returnValue = this.descriptor.getInterfacePolicy().selectAllObjectsUsingMultipleTableSubclassRead(this);
            this.executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return returnValue;
        }

        if (this.descriptor.hasTablePerClassPolicy() && this.descriptor.isAbstract()) {
            result = this.containerPolicy.containerInstance();
        } else {
            Object sopObject = getTranslationRow().getSopObject();
            boolean useOptimization = false;
            if (sopObject == null) {
                useOptimization = usesResultSetAccessOptimization(); 
            }        

            if (useOptimization) {
                DatabaseCall call = ((DatasourceCallQueryMechanism)this.queryMechanism).selectResultSet();
                this.executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Statement statement = call.getStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = call.getResult();
                DatabaseAccessor dbAccessor = (DatabaseAccessor)getAccessor();
                boolean exceptionOccured = false;
                try {
                    if (this.session.isUnitOfWork()) {
                        result = registerResultSetInUnitOfWork(resultSet, call.getFields(), call.getFieldsArray(), (UnitOfWorkImpl)this.session, this.translationRow); 
                    } else {
                        result = this.containerPolicy.containerInstance();
                        this.descriptor.getObjectBuilder().buildObjectsFromResultSetInto(this, resultSet, call.getFields(), call.getFieldsArray(), result);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException exception) {
                    exceptionOccured = true;
                    DatabaseException commException = dbAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(this.session, exception, call);
                    if (commException != null) {
                        throw commException;
                    }
                    throw DatabaseException.sqlException(exception, call, dbAccessor, this.session, false);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (resultSet != null) {
                            resultSet.close();
                        }
                        if (dbAccessor != null) {
                            if (statement != null) {
                                dbAccessor.releaseStatement(statement, call.getSQLString(), call, this.session);
                            }
                        }
                        if (call.hasAllocatedConnection()) {
                            getExecutionSession().releaseConnectionAfterCall(this);
                        }
                    } catch (RuntimeException cleanupException) {
                        if (!exceptionOccured) {
                            throw cleanupException;
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException cleanupSQLException) {
                        if (!exceptionOccured) {
                            throw DatabaseException.sqlException(cleanupSQLException, call, dbAccessor, this.session, false);
                        }
                    }
                }                
            } else {
                List<AbstractRecord> rows;
                if (sopObject != null) {
                    Object valuesIterator = this.containerPolicy.iteratorFor(getTranslationRow().getSopObject());
                    int size = this.containerPolicy.sizeFor(sopObject);
                    rows =  new ArrayList<AbstractRecord>(size);
                    while (this.containerPolicy.hasNext(valuesIterator)) {
                        Object memberSopObject = this.containerPolicy.next(valuesIterator, this.session);
                        DatabaseRecord memberRow = new DatabaseRecord(0);
                        memberRow.setSopObject(memberSopObject);
                        rows.add(memberRow);                        
                    }
                    this.executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } else {
                    rows = getQueryMechanism().selectAllRows();
                    this.executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // If using 1-m joins, must set all rows.
                    if (hasJoining() && this.joinedAttributeManager.isToManyJoin()) {
                        this.joinedAttributeManager.setDataResults(rows, this.session);
                    }
                    // Batch fetching in IN requires access to the rows to build the id array.
                    if ((this.batchFetchPolicy != null) && this.batchFetchPolicy.isIN()) {
                        this.batchFetchPolicy.setDataResults(rows);
                    }
                }

                if (this.session.isUnitOfWork()) {
                    result = registerResultInUnitOfWork(rows, (UnitOfWorkImpl)this.session, this.translationRow, true);// 
                } else {
                    if (rows instanceof ThreadCursoredList) {
                        result = this.containerPolicy.containerInstance();
                    } else {
                        result = this.containerPolicy.containerInstance(rows.size());
                    }
                    this.descriptor.getObjectBuilder().buildObjectsInto(this, rows, result);
                }

                if (sopObject != null) {
                    if (!this.descriptor.getObjectBuilder().isSimple()) {
                        // remove sopObject so it's not stuck in any value holder.
                        for (AbstractRecord row : rows) {
                            row.setSopObject(null);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (this.shouldIncludeData) {
                        ComplexQueryResult complexResult = new ComplexQueryResult();
                        complexResult.setResult(result);
                        complexResult.setData(rows);
                        result = complexResult;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the other (already registered) results and return them.
        if (this.descriptor.hasTablePerClassPolicy()) {
            result = this.containerPolicy.concatenateContainers(
                    result, this.descriptor.getTablePerClassPolicy().selectAllObjectsUsingMultipleTableSubclassRead(this), this.session);
        }

        // If the results were empty, then ensure they get cached still.
        if (shouldCacheQueryResults() && this.containerPolicy.isEmpty(result)) {
            this.temporaryCachedQueryResults = InvalidObject.instance();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

From my very limited understanding of eclipse link.I believe The translation row is the row retrieved by the batch fetch query. Does anybody have any ideas why this is being rendered as null.....any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like someone reported similar behavior through https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467046 but never followed up with more information. You might try filling a bug with the latest EclipseLink version and/or adding to this bug what you've written. If you can, step through the original query, as this query creates the translationRow and sets it in the query internal to the lazy relationship. When something is null that shouldn't be,I also look at concurrency of the objects involved - neither the queries or the entities being read should be accessed by multiple threads concurrently

Comment: I saw that, unfortunately it wasn't much help. I will create a new bug report for Eclipse Link and see if anybody has encountered this. Get some fresh eyes on it. Thank you Chris.